# Target in compiler project failed

Tags: c, compilation, target

How does work target in compilation (in C) ?
I am working on a project and I failed on that `#error You have to define a target in your compiler project properties.`

And I wonder what was exacly target in compilation and how does it works.

My compiler is GCC

**EDIT**

here is my error:
`In file included from ../../../RefFT/Common/src/SIGPROC_COMMON_ippdefs.h:55:0,
from ../../../RefFT/Common/src/SIGPROC_COMMON_memory_alloc.c:36:
../../../../../../../Generic/Common/Include/target_definition.h:195:6: error: #error You have to define a target in your compiler project properties.
 #error You have to define a target in your compiler \`

I work on a project that was compile for Iphone Target (might be compile with xcode) and I want to compile it with gcc.

Here is a part of the target_definition.h

```
#ifdef _X86_VC6_TARGET_
#define TARGET X86_VC6_TARGET
#elif defined _X86_VC7_1_TARGET_
#define TARGET X86_VC7_1_TARGET
#elif defined _X86_VC8_TARGET_
#define TARGET X86_VC8_TARGET
#elif defined _X86_VC9_TARGET_
#define TARGET X86_VC9_TARGET
#elif defined _X86_VC11_TARGET_
    #define TARGET X86_VC11_TARGET
#elif defined _X86_VC12_TARGET_
    #define TARGET X86_VC12_TARGET
#elif defined _X86_GCC_3_2_2_TARGET_
#define TARGET X86_GCC_3_2_2_TARGET
#elif defined _X86_GCC_4_1_1_TARGET_
    #define TARGET X86_GCC_4_1_1_TARGET
#elif defined _MACOS_TARGET_
#define __macos__
#define TARGET MACOS_TARGET
#elif defined _X86_MACOS_GCC_4_2_1_TARGET_
#define __macos__
#define TARGET X86_MACOS_GCC_4_2_1_TARGET
#elif defined _X86_MSYS_GCC_4_4_1_TARGET_
    #define TARGET X86_MSYS_GCC_4_4_1_TARGET
#elif defined _ARM11_IPHONEOS_GCC_4_2_1_TARGET_
#define TARGET ARM11_IPHONEOS_GCC_4_2_1_TARGET
#elif defined _IPHONEOS_TARGET_
#define TARGET IPHONEOS_TARGET
#elif defined _ARM9_VE4_TARGET_
#define TARGET ARM9_VE4_TARGET
#elif defined _ARM9_VC8_TARGET_
#define TARGET ARM9_VC8_TARGET
#elif defined _ARM9_GCC_TARGET_
#else
#error You have to define a target in your compiler \
```

Comment: It could help if you specified the compiler you used...

Comment: ...as well as the line within  the header/source file that error is emitted from,  including the surrounding lines in your question please. Please remember, we haven't a clue what your building.

Comment: This is not a C language issue.  C itself knows nothing about compilation targets.  The reference to "project properties" leads me to believe that it's an issue with how you are using some IDE.

Comment: You need to show code. That is obviously a custom error, and thus is triggered by code around it, not by something in the compiler. I expect you're trying to compile something intended for the MSVC compiler run from within Visual Studio, which has targets such as "Debug" and "Release" in the default generated project files.

Comment: Is it a new project you have set up in some IDE, or it is an existing project what you've just started to work on?

Comment: @simon it's an existing project

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am not working on a IDE I just creat a Makefile to compile with gcc

Comment: Always include the code around the actual error (the line that says `error:`). In this case: `../../../../../../../Generic/Common/Include/target_definition.h:195`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what compiler verson or OS, but from the code, you need to define the appropriate identifier (probably by using [the `-D` flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) passed to `gcc` via your makefile).

Here's the ones for GCC:

```
_X86_GCC_3_2_2_TARGET_
_X86_GCC_4_1_1_TARGET_   << Probably this one for Linux
_X86_MACOS_GCC_4_2_1_TARGET_
_X86_MSYS_GCC_4_4_1_TARGET_  << Or this one for Windows
_ARM11_IPHONEOS_GCC_4_2_1_TARGET_
_ARM9_GCC_TARGET_
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code expects one of several preprocessor macros to be externally defined, presumably to help it choose among various compiler-specific optimizations or non-standard features.  That you receive such an error when trying to build the project with `make` suggests either a poor or incomplete build system, or having skipped steps in some kind of pre-build configuration process.  Possibly both.

It might be that you can get past this particular issue by doing something like this:

```
make CFLAGS=-D_X86_GCC_4_1_1_TARGET_=1
```

instead of a bare `make`, but you really ought to read the builder / installer documentation, as there is probably a better way to go about it, and there may be other things you need to do.